# Calling publisher at a specific rate

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, rate, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a node that subscribes to a topic, does some computation and publishes the message on a different topic. The publish is implemented within subscriber callback function.

While the subscribed topic arrives at a different rate (and hence the callback), I would like to publish at a specific rate (100Hz). My implementation is in C++ and I am running Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. Please let me know the best way to handle this

thank you

---

Thank you
I have couple of follow-up questions

1. I am publishing within the subscriber callback (when I receive a topic, I call a callback, do some computation and publishing within the callback itself). How do I not modify the subscriber loop rate, but only change the publisher rate? Adding ros::Rate in main will affect both subscriber and publisher?
2. On using timer, what should be the timeCallback? If I use the subscriber callback for this, this will not subscribe to a topic at a rate it is arriving which is different than my publisher's required rate

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338523/calling-publisher-at-a-specific-rate/) by [prj1508](https://answers.ros.org/users/46089/prj1508/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-11-25**:
There are several ways you can do that:
Enclose the subscriber in the spin loop:

```
ros::Rate loop_rate(100);
while (ros::ok())
{
 //Publish here your values
 ros::spinOnce();
 loop_rate.sleep();
}
```

or set a [Timer](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers) to publish every 100secs:

```
ros::Timer timer = nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(1/100), timerCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Weasfas 's answer is correct for setting a particular rate of publishing and subscribing using `sleep()`. Accroding to your other questions you might need to use a timer because :

1. You should not do too much things within a subscriber, imagine you receive messages at a rate of `100Hz` but you take `1 sec` to execute the callback, you will end up loosing data or process old data that has been stored in the callback queue. You can use a global variable to store the message data and in another function you can use the global variable and publish what's needed. About the Rate, yes it will affect both subscribers and publisher (if the publisher is within the callback). Spinning at a define rate means that your callbacks are **triggered** at this rate (but it will be executed as many times as messages have been stored in the queue while waiting)
2. You should use the timer to bind it with the publisher function and define the rate at 100 for calling this function that will use the global variable that gets the data from the callback. So you hsould have one callback function to store the messages and another function that is called by the timer that deals with the data and then publish it.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested by Weasfas in the comment above, you can use a [ros::Timer](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers). The following snippet should do the work:

```
ros::Publisher my_pub = nh.advertise<Message>("my_topic", queue);
ros::Timer timer = nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(1/100), timerCallback);
Message modified_message;

...

// timer callback. Pub lishes modified message on a specified frequency
void timerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent &) {
  my_pub.publish(modified_message);
}

...

void subCallback(Message message_in){
// do some processing of the message_in and update modified_message
...
//
}
```

You can also check this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/240768/how-can-the-subscriber-subscribe-once-every-2-seconds/) regarding using `throttle` to republish data to another topic, either at a maximum bandwidth or maximum message rate.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1